# Momentjs isDST function doesn't return correct result

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to detect if my date is within DST or not. What I'm trying to do is to follow the documentation: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-daylight-saving-time/

And the following code return `false` all the time:

```
import moment from 'moment';

console.log(moment('2020-12-31').isDST());
console.log(moment('2027-05-23').isDST());

console.log(moment([2011, 2, 12]).isDST());
console.log(moment([2018, 8, 14]).isDST());

console.log(moment().isDST());
```

Live demo is available here: https://repl.it/repls/WatchfulDelayedLight

Can't understand what's wrong here.

Comment: Please check your timezone is have DST or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use moment-timezone instead and specifically set the timezone. Otherwise it will use the local timezone on the machine which seems like it doesn't have DST.

```
import moment from 'moment-timezone';

console.log(moment.tz('2020-12-31', 'Europe/London').isDST());
console.log(moment.tz('2027-05-23', 'Europe/London').isDST());

console.log(moment.tz([2011, 2, 12], 'Europe/London').isDST());
console.log(moment.tz([2018, 8, 14], 'Europe/London').isDST());

console.log(moment.tz(null, 'Europe/London').isDST());
```

Comment: I do have only offset! How can I check whether my date falls on DST or not? I tried this `moment.utc().utcOffset('-05:00').isDST()` not working!